# faster and efficient way of deleting rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

**what i am trying to do.**

I have two worksheets "dashboard" and "temp calc".I am trying to delete rows based on two different conditions in each worksheet.

**Dashboard**- delete rows if column number 15 <> active

delete rows if column number 10 <> E&D,ESG,PLM SER,VPD,PLM Prod.

**Temp calc** = Delete rows if column number 6 is blank

delete rows if column number 3n1
where n1 and n2 are dates taken from range("n1" and "n2") in dashboard.

**What I have tried.**

1. using a for loop
2. using a filter
3. arrays(I am unable to actually do this using an array

**My Problem**

these methods are very slow and my data is around 1,68,000(grows on a weekly basis).So I am looking for alternatives to what I have tried. Basically something which will do this fast.

**my codes I have tried.**
the below code works but it takes upto 6-10 minutes depending on the data

```
                    Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
                    Range("A4").Select
                    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    For x = lastrow To 4 Step -1
                     If Cells(x, 15).Value <> "Active" Or (Cells(x, 10).Value <> "E&D" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "ESG" _
                     And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "PLM SER" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "VPD" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "PLM PROD") Then
                    Rows(x).Delete
                    End If
                    Next x
```

The below code uses the autofilter method.the problem is that data which is not in my compare range is left after filtering(i.e if my n1 =1st Jan and n2=30th jan 2013. the filter will still leave behind data that is not in the n1 and n2 range.

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp Calc")



   '~~> Start Date and End Date
   Sheets("Dashboard").Select
N1 = Range("n1").Value
N2 = Range("n2").Value
Sheets("Temp Calc").Select

With ws

'~~> Remove any filters
.AutoFilterMode = False

'~~> Get the last row
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'~~> Identify your data range
Set FltrRng = .Range("A1:F" & lRow)

'~~> Filter the data as per your criteria
With FltrRng
'~~> First filter on blanks
.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="="

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'~~> Delete the filtered blank rows
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

ws.ShowAllData

'~~> Next filter on Start Date
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<" & N1, Operator:=xlAnd
'~~> Finally filter on End Date
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">" & N2, Operator:=xlAnd

'~~> Filter on col 6 for CNF
'.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="CNF"

'~~> Delete the filtered rows
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'~~> Remove any filters
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Apologies in case the question is not adequate.
Any alternatives which will speed up what I am trying to do is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Auto filter is fast - definitely the way to go - but it hides data rows and doesn't delete them. Since your code turns the filter off at the end, the hidden rows come back. Instead, you should apply the filter, select all, copy, paste into new sheet, and delete the old sheet. This will be very fast - and do exactly what you are asking for.

Apologies that I am not posting working code - typing on ipad...

Comment: not a problem floris.But as you can see i am deleting the data then removing the filter so shouldn't it work?

Comment: You only seem to delete the row "right below" using `.offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete` . That is not "all the invisible rows"

Comment: did not realise that. what changes should i make

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With Sheets("Dashboard")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)


        For x = Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(x, 15).Value <> "Active" Or (.Cells(x, 10).Value <> "E&D" And .Cells(x, 10).Value <> "ESG" _
             And .Cells(x, 10).Value <> "PLM SER" And .Cells(x, 10).Value <> "VPD" And .Cells(x, 10).Value <> "PLM PROD") Then
                Rng.Rows(x).Delete
            End If
        Next

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: hello santosh i have used this as posted in my question :)
but it takes 6-10 minutes and i want to bring that count down

Comment: @mathew Can you try running this code & see how much time it takes.

Comment: yes i will do that and post the results.
currently there is another code running :) which will take around 5-10 minutes

Comment: i am curious about the changes you have made. Can you elaborate, how they would make a difference

Comment: @mathew `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` & `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` do speed up the code. Also its a good practice to delete the row from bottom so i used a for loop step -1.

Comment: i am doing all of the above. I understand the misunderstanding since i have not posted the complete code due to the size

Comment: santosh my data starts from range("a4")
what are the changes i would have to do 
i know x = Rng.rows.count To 4 Step -1 
but what are the other changes

Comment: @mathew It should be `For x = Rng.Rows.Count To 4 Step -1`

Comment: Haha apologies for the formatting nothing else ?
also the condition i want to check is if col number 10 contains E&D,ESG,PLM Ser and so on anything else should be chucked out is "AND" the correct way of doing it.
Should code for column no 15 and 16 run separately, i think it will check only if false right?

Comment: @mathew Now the code is good to go. Give it a try & let me know if it worked for you (time saving).

Comment: it took 14 minutes and 7 seconds to run. which is more time than the code ive used

Comment: @mathew Oops strange result. Goodluck